# Minimax in Scala

Tags: scala, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I'm trying to adapt the minimax algorithm from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) for my implementation of TicTacToe in Scala. I want the X player, -1, to try and maximize his score. I found a cool static evaluation function [here](http://kartikkukreja.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/heuristic-function-for-tic-tac-toe/) which I would like to use. It returns positive numbers if the board is a good board for the player, and negative numbers if the board is bad for the player. I've tried a few variations and X continues to just make the first move available. The method is below, the method and evaluation function can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/odhranroche/7716028).

Is there something glaringly obvious about this that I'm missing?

```
// player X = -1, player O = 1
def minmax(board:Array[Int], height:Int, player:Int):Double={
  if(height == 0)
    evaluatePosition(board, player)

  var alpha = -player * Double.PositiveInfinity;

  val allBoards = makeAllPossibleMoves(board, player) // array of child boards
  for(b <- allBoards){
    val score = minmax(b, height-1, -player)
    alpha = if (player == -1) Math.max(alpha, score) else Math.min(alpha, score)
  }

  alpha
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `alpha` is initialized with the wrong value:

```
var alpha = -player * Double.PositiveInfinity
```

means that in case of the `X` player (-1) `alpha` is initialized as

```
var alpha = - (-1) * Double.PositiveInfinity
```

which can be simplified to

```
var alpha = Double.PositiveInfinity
```

Thus, **alpha cannot increase anymore**, i.e.

```
alpha = if (player == -1) Math.max(alpha, score) else //...
```

will have no effect. The reverse should be true for the other player (1), where `alpha` is initialized as negative infinity and thus cannot be mimized anymore. Thus, you should be able to fix this by simply removing the `-1` factor from the initialization of `alpha`:

```
var alpha = player * Double.PositiveInfinity
```

Comment: Of course. Thanks for the clear explanation. I also had to explicitly return `evaluatePosition(board, player)` to get a result. It works now, but oddly it seems to perform better when `height` is set to 0 than when `height` > 0. I think this may just be a quirk of the evaluation function.